# Roblox is lagging

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

I have been lagging in Roblox and it happens every time I log in.
The symptoms of the lagging include:

- colors going haywire
- text blurring (even my name)
- and eventually Roblox crashes

I have tried:

- restarting my device
- closing Roblox
- and updating my version

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Is your graphics card bad?

Comment: Have you tried all these fixes? mentioned here? [https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/reduce-roblox-lag/](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/reduce-roblox-lag/)

Comment: I use hand held not PC